# Should I say "I derive the equation", "I derivate the equation" or "I differentiate the equation"?

Tags: word-choice

Should I say "I derive the equation", "I derivate the equation" or "I differentiate the equation"?

I mean in this context:

```
Here is equation (1).
I _____________ equation (1) and get the following result...
```

another context

```
Equation (2) is the derivative of (1) or
Equation (2) is the differential (1) ?
```

When should I use one term or the other for contexts like that?

Comment: You are differentiating both sides of equation (1). Although it's not strictly accurate, " I differentiate equation (1)" would be correctly understood. To derive equation (1) means something quite different, namely to prove that equation (1) is a consequence of some other information. And "I derivate equation (1)" is not English; "derivate" is a noun, not a verb.

Comment: @SpaceDog I agree with AndreasBlass that "differentiate" is the best of your options. But in many/most cases, we would say "I take the derivative of [equation 1]"

Comment: @SAH I suspect this usage is quite regional, i.e. "differentiate" might be more common on one side of the pond, "take the derivative of" more common on the other. Are you from either "side", or from another region entirely?

Comment: @Chappo - I am from another country, non-native english speaker. I am trying to  say this as americans would do.

Comment: Both in math and out, "derive" and "differentiate" have two entirely different meanings.  You can't substitute one for the other.

Comment: @SpaceDog I believe Americans would say "take the derivative." ("Derivative")

Comment: **differentiate** via TFD: *v.tr.* **4.** *Mathematics* To calculate the derivative or differential of (a function). (American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2016) ; **4.** (Mathematics) *maths* to perform a differentiation on (a quantity, expression, etc) (Collins) ;  **4.** *Math.* to obtain the differential or the derivative of.  (Random House Kernerman Webster's)

Comment: @SpaceDog P.S. We usually don't talk of "taking the derivative of an equation" (except MAYBE in differential equations or other math subfields higher than the one I attained). We would instead talk about "taking the derivative of [a side of (an) equation]" (="taking the derivative of an expression")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the most basic terms, the *derivative* of a function is the rate of change of that function. You compute the *derivative* by *differentiating* the function.

I have done a quick search to show some basic usage of the two words, and pretty much the first result was:

https://revisionmaths.com/advanced-level-maths-revision/pure-maths/calculus/differentiation

That has some examples in the text of using the verb *differentiate* to mean "compute the *derivative*".

Answer (score 2):

I would personally say : taking the derivative on both sides of equation (1) we get.... I don't see the need to express it in one word, I just say what step to take.